# Order Tasks in a List View

Tags: 2013, tasks, view

I'm new to Sharepoint. Google hasn't given me a straight answer on this so hoping to find it here.

Can I custom order a Task list view?

In case that is not clear, I would like to order tasks in a View (for example a View that lists only the tasks I am assigned to) not on any specific column but simply as chosen. Is this possible? If not, are there any lists that allow this? Or any work-arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do it:

1. Use additional column
2. Use [ReorderItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.reorderitems.aspx) functionality

In first case you create additional column "Order" of type Number, and set the view to order by this column.

The second approach is much more interesting. In this case, if you don't want to involve code customizations, you have to use list of type "Links". For links lists, SharePoint provides interface for defining items order:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no way to convert a list from one type to another, thus essentialy you have to recreate your existing list as a Links list if you want this functionality in place.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Because the view would be of a user's tasks, I can't see how 1 would work, as I would need a new column for every user wouldn't I? (I should add here that a task could be assigned to more than one person) Unless there is some way to add a column who's values are dependant on the user?

Comment: I'll have a look into 2. But my understanding is that I would need to store the task order for each User somewhere else, which could make things complicated if ever they went out of sync! :)

Comment: Steve, you can define a list view to show only tasks  of current user. So that having only one view each user will see only his tasks there. No matter which approach you pick, user will be able to change order of items, either by setting a value to the additional field "Order", or by using this "Change Item Order" GUI.

Comment: Sorry I really should've said it at the outset, but there are tasks that can be assigned to multiple users!

Comment: Well, this definitely makes things much more complicated. In this case, ideally you should have a custom solution which allows users to change items order and then stores the information about items order somewhere in cookies/local storage/user profile properties/..., so that it will be stored per user. But for now you might still want to try one of the approaches I presented in the answer, especially if multiple assignment is a rare case.

Comment: ok, thanks for clearing this up and apologies for not explaining the many-to-many relationship properly at the outset.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use list views. By default there are several views:

1. All tasks
2. My Tasks
3. Due today
4. Active task
5. By assigned to
6. By my groups

You can choose one of them. If you need additional views you can create it from list menu(create view option in the ribbon).

[image]

Comment: as far as I understood the question, Steve meant he wants to manually define order of the items.

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev, one of the possibility is to create additional view that displays items ordered by some field. This query can be specified in this custom view, in you answer it is the first approach.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, sorry I don't have enough rep to up-vote your answer. Andrey is right in that I don't want the items sorted by a field like a date, but on a field that is incremented numbers that the user can change. What complicates it is that 1 task might be viewed by multiple users, so if in 1 user's view it is ordered 4th, in another user's view it should be able to be ranked 3rd. If that makes sense.